# Why is the 'o' in 'antimony' pronounced differently than that in 'antinomy'?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation, ipa

So, 'antimony' comes from the latin 'antimonium', wherein the 'o' is pronounced as an /ō/. So, the 'o' in 'antimony' is pronounced as an /ō/.

'Antinomy' comes from the latin 'antinomia', wherein the 'o' is also pronounced as an /ō/. However, the 'o' in 'antinomy' is pronounced /ə/.

Why is this?

Answer (score 4):

It's because of stress patterns.

*Antinomy* (an-TI-no-my) is stressed on the second syllable alone, so the other three syllables have reduced vowels. The syllable immediately following the stress is apt to get swallowed when you have two unstressed syllables following as you have here.

*Antimony* (AN-ti-MO-ny) is stressed on both the first and third syllables, so those two do not have reduced vowels.  The first carries primary stress and the third carries secondary stress. But that’s still enough to stop it from reducing to a schwa.

Answer (score 1):

if you check the pronunciation of both the words in Oxford dictionary, it's the same. There is no difference. I have provided the link below for your convenience.

Antimony--https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antimony
Antinomy--https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/antinomy

Best regards!

Comment: I recommend you [look again](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/antimony). As with so many of these (*secritry, medcine*), the British reduce syllables that Americans do not.

Comment: You are right. I noticed this with several other words. Thanks Sir!